# equivalent conditions of u.a.n

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $X_{1},X_{2},\cdots$
  are independent random variables with mean $E[X_{k}]=m_{k}$ and variance $Var(X_{k})=\sigma_{k}^2$, and define $D_{n}^2=Var(X_{1}+\cdots+ X_{n})$.Show that
$\{\frac{X_{k}-m_{k}}{D_{n}},1\le k\le n,n\ge 1\}$ are u.a.n sequences iff $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\max\limits _{1\le k\le n}\frac{\sigma_{k}^2}{D_{n}^2}=0$. I have figured out the sufficient ,but the neccesity I have no idea .Would you give me some suggestion?Thank you.

Comment: Could you define "u.a.n." (uniform asymptotic normality?)?

Comment: @Davide Giraudo $\{a_{nk},1\le k\le n,n\ge 1\}$are u.a.n sequences if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\max\limits _{1\le k\le n}P\{|a_{nk}|\ge \varepsilon\}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that u.a.n. does not hold hence there exists $\varepsilon\gt0$ and some sequences $(n(i))$ and $(k(i))$ such that $n(i)\to\infty$ when $i\to\infty$, $1\leqslant k(i)\leqslant n(i)$ and $P[|X_{k(i)}-m_{k(i)}|\geqslant\varepsilon D_{n(i)}]\geqslant\varepsilon$ for every $i$. In particular, for every $i$, 
$$
\sigma^2_{k(i)}=E[(X_{k(i)}-m_{k(i)})^2)\geqslant(\varepsilon D_{n(i)})^2P[|X_{k(i)}-m_{k(i)}|\geqslant\varepsilon D_{n(i)}]\geqslant\varepsilon^3D_{n(i)}^2,
$$
hence $\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n(i)}\sigma^2_k/D_{n(i)}^2\geqslant\varepsilon^3$. This contradicts the condition that $\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\sigma^2_k/D_{n}^2$ converges to zero.

(You said you figured out the other implication.)

Comment: @Did.Thank you for your answer,but how about the other implication?Maybe there is something wrong with my expression.I just want to verify the other.Thank you for your time and consideration again.

Comment: Since you wrote "I have figured out the sufficient", I thought you had figured out the other implication. If you want somebody to check your proof, show your proof.

Comment: ,sorry.I think I'm confusing the sufficency with necessity .Thank you for your time and consideration again.